# How best do I keep a long running Go program, running?

Tags: go, daemon, goroutine

I've a long running server written in Go.  Main fires off several goroutines where the logic of the program executes.  After that main does nothing useful.  Once main exits, the program will quit.  The method I am using right now to keep the program running is just a simple call to fmt.Scanln().  I'd like to know how others keep main from exiting.  Below is a basic example.  What ideas or best practices could be used here?

I considered creating a channel and delaying exit of main by receiving on said channel, but I think that could be problematic if all my goroutines become inactive at some point.

Side note:  In my server (not the example), the program isn't actually running connected to a shell, so it doesn't really make sense to interact with the console anyway.  For now it works, but I'm looking for the "correct" way, assuming there is one.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go forever()
    //Keep this goroutine from exiting
    //so that the program doesn't end.
    //This is the focus of my question.
    fmt.Scanln()
}

func forever() {
    for ; ; {
    //An example goroutine that might run
    //indefinitely. In actual implementation
    //it might block on a chanel receive instead
    //of time.Sleep for example.
        fmt.Printf("%v+\n", time.Now())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: I found 6 ways to make it - http://pliutau.com/different-ways-to-block-go-runtime-forever/

Comment: For anyone who is trying to deploy forever running go application in `Marathon` or `DC/OS`, do not use `fmt.Scanln` method, you will get `container exit with code 0`, i.e it somehow gets an input from the console. Use any of the methods mentioned in the answers below, life will be easier.
#GO #DOCKER #MARATHON #DCOS

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The current design of Go's runtime assumes that the programmer is responsible for detecting when to terminate a goroutine and when to terminate the program. The programmer needs to compute the termination condition for goroutines and also for the entire program. A program can be terminated in a normal way by calling [`os.Exit`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit) or by returning from the `main()` function.

Creating a channel and delaying exit of `main()` by immediately receiving on said channel is a valid approach of preventing `main` from exiting. But it does not solve the problem  of detecting when to terminate the program.

If the number of goroutines cannot be computed before the `main()` function enters the wait-for-all-goroutines-to-terminate loop, you need to be sending deltas so that `main` function can keep track of how many goroutines are in flight:

```
// Receives the change in the number of goroutines
var goroutineDelta = make(chan int)

func main() {
    go forever()

    numGoroutines := 0
    for diff := range goroutineDelta {
        numGoroutines += diff
        if numGoroutines == 0 { os.Exit(0) }
    }
}

// Conceptual code
func forever() {
    for {
        if needToCreateANewGoroutine {
            // Make sure to do this before "go f()", not within f()
            goroutineDelta <- +1

            go f()
        }
    }
}

func f() {
    // When the termination condition for this goroutine is detected, do:
    goroutineDelta <- -1
}
```

An alternative approach is to replace the channel with [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). A drawback of this approach is that `wg.Add(int)` needs to be called before calling `wg.Wait()`, so it is necessary to create at least 1 goroutine in `main()` while subsequent goroutines can be created in any part of the program:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    // Create at least 1 goroutine
    wg.Add(1)
    go f()

    go forever()
    wg.Wait()
}

// Conceptual code
func forever() {
    for {
        if needToCreateANewGoroutine {
            wg.Add(1)
            go f()
        }
    }
}

func f() {
    // When the termination condition for this goroutine is detected, do:
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Thorough answer and great explanation.  I will likely go with a channel receive, as my go routines are buried in other packages that do the serving.  I do not want to do goroutine counting everywhere.  The channel will work well if I decide to add shutdown logic to the program using signals or some other IPC...Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

Block forever. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go forever()
    select {} // block forever
}

func forever() {
    for {
        fmt.Printf("%v+\n", time.Now())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: this approach no longer seems to work in latest go, throws following error `goroutine 1 [select (no cases)]:
main.main()`

Comment: @dark_ruby: It works on the latest version of Go: `go version devel +13c44d2 Sat Jun 20 10:35:38 2015 +0000 linux/amd64`. How can we reproduce your failure exactly? Be very precise, for example, "latest go" is too vague.

Comment: @peterSO yes you're right, i just happened to use `select {}` on its own, but that causes `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`, I need to do more reading on how exactly it works, and why doesnt it cause deadlock in above code.

Comment: Some more https://blog.sgmansfield.com/2016/06/how-to-block-forever-in-go/

Answer (score 37):

Nobody mentioned `signal.Notify(c chan<- os.Signal, sig ...os.Signal)`

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    go forever()

    quitChannel := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(quitChannel, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    <-quitChannel
    //time for cleanup before exit
    fmt.Println("Adios!")
}

func forever() {
    for {
        fmt.Printf("%v+\n", time.Now())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Comment: For a running service, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Excellent answer! So simple.

Answer (score 31):

Go's [runtime](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) package has a function called [`runtime.Goexit`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#Goexit) that will do exactly what you want.

> Calling Goexit from the main goroutine terminates that goroutine
>     without func main returning. Since func main has not returned,
>     the program continues execution of other goroutines.
>     If all other goroutines exit, the program crashes.

Example in the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7-bucr63UI)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        fmt.Println("Go 1")
    }()
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
        fmt.Println("Go 2")
    }()

    runtime.Goexit()

    fmt.Println("Exit")
}
```

Comment: That is very cool. But, I have to wonder, why they chose to make the program crash instead of having it exit gracefully. Is the idea that you'd have another goroutine handling the shutdown of the application and it will call exit when it receives a signal? I'm just wondering how one would properly use this function.

Comment: @Nate that is correct. For example check out this [code](https://play.golang.org/p/8N5Yr3ZNPT), Go routine 2 exits the program and the program does not crash. If Goexit crashes your program it's because all other Go routines have completed. I quite like how it crashes, let's me know it's not doing anything, unlike say `select{}` which would block forever even though nothing is happening.

Comment: like this one better

Answer (score 16):

Here is a simple block forever using channels

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    go forever()
    <-done // Block forever
}

func forever() {
    for {
        fmt.Printf("%v+\n", time.Now())
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could daemonize the process using Supervisor (http://supervisord.org/). Your function forever would just be a process that it runs, and it would handle the part of your function main. You would use the supervisor control interface to start/shutdown/check on your process.

Comment: An interesting system, but it appears it's an actual program, not Go code I would use.  I'm going to edit my question, as I am specifically trying to figure out best practices for keeping main from exiting.  Right now, I'm using fmt.Scanln(), I want to know if there is a better way...But thanks for the tip to Supervisor.  I could see us investigating it further.