# Running a Go routine indefinitely

Tags: go

I have a function that calls another function that returns a chan array. I currently have a for loop looping over the range in the array which runs the program indefinitely outputting the channel updates as the come through.

```
func getRoutes() {
      for r := range rtu {
        if r.Type == 24 {
          fmt.Printf("Route added: %s via %s\n",r.Dst.String(),r.Gw.String())
        } else if r.Type == 25 {
          fmt.Printf("Route deleted: %s via %s\n",r.Dst.String(),r.Gw.String())
        }
      }
}
```

When I call getRoutes() from main() everything works as planned though, it's blocking the application. I've tried calling `go getRoutes()` from `main()` though it appears as if the function isn't being called at all.

How can I run this function in the background in a non-blocking way using go routines?

Comment: Here is my answer from the same question asked a while back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543835/how-best-do-i-keep-a-long-running-go-program-running/38856572#38856572 - It uses a method from the runtime pkg.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the primary goroutine at `main` exits, all goroutines you might have spawned will be orphaned and eventually die.

You could keep the main goroutine running forever with an infinite loop with `for {}`, but you might want to keep an exit channel instead:

```golang
exit := make(chan string)

// Spawn all you worker goroutines, and send a message to exit when you're done.

for {
    select {
    case <-exit:
        os.Exit(0)
    }
}
```

**Update:** Cerise Limón pointed out that goroutines are just killed immediately when main exits. I think this is supposed to be the officially specified behaviour.

**Another update:** The for-select works better when you have multiple ways to exit / multiple exit channels. For a single exit channel you could just do

```
<-exit
```

at the end instead of a `for` and `select` loop.

Comment: Getting syntax error on the `select` statement: `syntax error: unexpected semicolon or newline, expecting comma or }`

Comment: Think I missed a colon at the end of the case statement.

Comment: More precisely, the program exits when the `main` function returns. The goroutines do not continue in an orphaned state where they eventually die.  All execution in the process stops when the program exits.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I've seen some weird behaviour with this - goroutines logging to STDOUT long after main exits. Maybe `go test --race` just puts the program in the background or something, or runs main inside a harness.

Comment: You don't need a select statement for a single channel receive, and you don't need a for loop when you're simply going to call `os.Exit`. If you're waiting on more than one goroutine, you should be using a WaitGroup too.

Comment: Also, you're recommendation for using `for {}` is also incorrect, as a busy loop is always a programming error, it wastes 100% of one CPU, and will eventually cause the runtime scheduler to hang.

Comment: Just to add a bit, instead of a for {} you could use sync.WaitGroup.

Comment: @JimB an empty `for{}` would be a busy loop, but this has a select in it, which blocks immediately. Now that I think about it more, though, the for select is only necessary for different channels. A single exit can work without it.

Answer (score 5):

Although other people have answered this, I think their solutions can be simplified in some cases.

Take this code snippet:

```
func main() {
    go doSomething()
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}

func doSomething() {
     for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Doing something...")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
     }
}
```

When `main()` begins executing, it spawns a thread to concurrently execute `doSomething()`. It then immediately executes `fmt.Println("Done.")`, and the `main()` finishes.

When `main()` finishes, all other goroutines will be orphaned, and die.

To avoid this, we can put a blocking operation at the end of `main()` that waits for input from a goroutine. It's easiest to do this with a channel:

```
var exit = make(chan bool)

func main() {
    go doSomething()
    <-exit // This blocks until the exit channel receives some input
    fmt.Println("Done.")
}

func doSomething() {
     for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fmt.Println("Doing something...")
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
     }
     exit<-true // Notify main() that this goroutine has finished
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `main()` returns before `getRoutes()`-goroutine finishes. When `main()` returns, the program exits, thereby killing all the running goroutines. (It's also totally possible that `main()` returns even before the goroutine gets a chance to get scheduled by go runtime.)

If you want `main()` (or any other function) to wait for a group of goroutines to finish, you'd have to make the function explicitly wait somehow. There're multiple ways to do that. [`sync.WaitGroup.Wait()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) can be used to wait for a group of the goroutines to finish. You could also use channels to communicate when goroutines are done.