# CRON job in Go not running as expected

Tags: go

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/robfig/cron"
)

func main() {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("@every 3m", func() { fmt.Println("Every 3 min") })
    c.Start()
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

The problem is when I run the code using `go run` it just prints `Done` then exits. I am just trying to print the function every 3 minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does this:

1. Initiates a new `cron` instance:

   ```
   c := cron.New()
   ```
2. Adds a cron job:

   ```
   c.AddFunc("@every 3m", func() { fmt.Println("Every 3 min") })
   ```
3. Starts the cron instance in a new goroutine (in the background):

   ```
   c.Start()
   ```
4. Prints "Done":

   ```
   fmt.Println("Done")
   ```
5. Then exits.

If you want your program to keep running, you need to make it *do something* that keeps it running.  If there is nothing else you need your program to do, just have it wait for something to finish that never finishes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9544599/13860) for some suggestions along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

Extending on @Flimzy answer, if you want your program to sit and do nothing, just add `select {}` to it

Your code would be something like this:

```
func main() {
    c := cron.New()
    c.AddFunc("@every 3m", func() { fmt.Println("Every 3 min") })
    c.Start()
    fmt.Println("Done")
    select {}
}
```